# How to create a looping url programmatically to scrape

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have this line of code I am trying to scrape; however, I am lost in how I can make the python code scrape a loop and save everything so I can .csv everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=bodyshop&geo_location_terms=Fort+Lauderdale%2C+FL"

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

from link in links:
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class", "info"})

from item in g_data:
    print item.content[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "adressLocality"})[0].text.replace(',', '')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "adressRegion"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        print item.contents[1].find_all("li", {"class": "primary"})[0].text
```

I know that with this code:

```
url_page2 = url + '&page=' + str(2) '&s=relevance'
```

I can loop to the second page, but how could one loop to all the page results of the website and make the results available in a .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Make an endless loop incrementing the page number starting from `1` and exit it when you'll get no results. Define a list of fields to extract and rely on the `itemprop` attribute to get the field values. Collect items in a list of dictionaries which you can later write into a csv file:

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=bodyshop&geo_location_terms=Fort%20Lauderdale%2C%20FL&page={page}&s=relevance"
fields = ["name", "streetAddress", "addressLocality", "addressRegion", "postalCode", "telephone"]

data = []
index = 1
while True:
    url = url.format(page=index)
    index += 1

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    page_results = soup.select('div.result')
    # exiting the loop if no results
    if not page_results:
        break

    for item in page_results:
        result = dict.fromkeys(fields)
        for field in fields:
            try:
                result[field] = item.find(itemprop=field).get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        data.append(result)

    break  # DELETE ME

pprint(data)
```

For the first page, it prints:

```
[{'addressLocality': u'Fort Lauderdale,',
  'addressRegion': u'FL',
  'name': u"Abernathy's Paint And Body Shop",
  'postalCode': u'33315',
  'streetAddress': u'1927 SW 1st Ave',
  'telephone': u'(954) 522-8923'},

  ...

 {'addressLocality': u'Fort Lauderdale,',
  'addressRegion': u'FL',
  'name': u'Mega Auto Body Shop',
  'postalCode': u'33304',
  'streetAddress': u'828 NE 4th Ave',
  'telephone': u'(954) 523-9331'}]
```